# Presenting a detail view controller from a map annotation in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I've researched on this topic for almost 3 days straight trying to figure out how to present my detail view controller by clicking on the info button of a map annotation in my map view controller. Basically, I can get the annotation to show, but when I click the annotation, nothing happens. I would like to have it present my detail view controller, the same way that when that same item is clicked on in my table view controller, it goes directly to its respective detail view.

Any help would be much, much appreciated! 
[This is the image of the map annotation I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt93Q.png)

Below is my code for my MapViewController. I feel like there is something wrong or something is missing in either my prepareForSegue or annotationView functions.

```
extension MapViewController {

  // 1
  @objc(mapView:viewForAnnotation:) func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if let annotation = annotation as? Annotations {

      let reuseID = "pin"

      var view: MKPinAnnotationView
      if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseID)
            as? MKPinAnnotationView { // 2
          dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
          view = dequeuedView
      } else {
        // 3
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.init(type: .detailDisclosure) as UIButton
      }
      return view
    }
    return nil
  }

  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
      print(view.annotation?.title)
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "moreDetail", sender: self)
    }

  }


  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "moreDetail") {
      // pass data to next view
      let destViewController:PancakeHouseViewController = segue.destination as! PancakeHouseViewController
      destViewController.viaSegue = sender as! MKAnnotationView
    }
  }

}
```

I have also included a variable inside my detail view controller (PancakeHouseViewController)... I don't know if it's supposed to be there or not.

```
var viaSegue = MKAnnotationView()
```

Comment: binded segue is present segue type right ?

Comment: correct. It's just that nothing happens when I push the detail disclosure button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem may just be in the method signature for `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`. It should be:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
```

Comment: By removing the ! from UIControl, the detail disclosure button still does not activate and segue to the PancakeHouseViewController

Comment: Did you add the `_` before the `mapView` argument?

Comment: Ah wow!! It worked!! But it only presents me with the default PancakeHouseViewController... Not the one that is linked up to each specific pancake house.

Comment: You will have to set up the `PancakeHouseViewController` inside the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "moreDetail") {
      // pass data to next view
      let destViewController:PancakeHouseViewController = segue.destination as! PancakeHouseViewController
      destViewController.viaSegue = sender as! MKAnnotationView
    }
  }

Comment: Maybe that will be enough - it depends what the `PancakeHouseViewController` does with the `viaSegue` property. But that's kind of a separate problem to your original question, and it is going to be very specific to your app.

Comment: I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. Thanks!